# how do you filter for rows in that are not NA?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to filter for rows that are NOT "NA" using the filter command. How do I do that?

Where "Dose_extract_IBUPROFEN" is the data frame, and "Drug3" is the variable for which a want to filter rows that are NOT missing (NA), I tried the following, which does not work.

```
filter(Dose_extract_IBUPROFEN, Drug3 != NA)
```

Comment: `complete.cases`? I think it depends. `airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]`. `dplyr` column specific: `airquality %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Solar.R))`

Comment: or `is.na` you can use

Answer (score 1):

You should use `!is.na(Drug3)` instead of `Drug3!=NA` because you cannot use normal comparison operators with `NA`.